# VB.NET: How to overload Dictionary.Item(TKey)

Tags: vb.net

I created my own Dictionary class, based on the .NET Dictionary.

Now I want to overload then Item() Method. This works fine with the following code:

```
Public Overloads Property Item(ByVal key As TKey) As TValue
   Get
       Return Nothing 
   End Get
   Set(ByVal value As TValue)
      MyBase.Item(key) = value
   End Set
End Property
```

When I now use Dictionary.Item(Key) to access a value I get Nothing. But when I use the Dictionary(Key) syntax I get the value and not Nothing.

How can I correctly overload Dictionary.Item(Key) AND Dictionary(Key)?

Thank you
Torben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property must be marked `Default` to enable the indexer syntax.

```
Public Overloads Default Property Item(ByVal key As TKey) As TValue
   Get
       Return Nothing 
   End Get
   Set(ByVal value As TValue)
      MyBase.Item(key) = value
   End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Using *Overloads* is a giant red flag.  Yes, it suppresses the warning when the OP is actually inheriting Dictionary.  No, that won't work well in practice, it shadows the base indexer.

Comment: @Hans I had assumed that `TKey` is distinct from the base’s key but upon reflection that’s of course nonsense.

Comment: @Torben: Hans is right, that won’t work (and more importantly there is **no** way to make this work reliably). This breaks inheritance in a bad way as soon as you try using your dictionary interchangeably with other dictionary implementations.